# 3D plotting y = x^2

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I know I ask a lot of questions here, but I'm still learning and searching for answers on google, but I can't seem to find out how to do what I'm looking for; this is what I want to do: I would like to 3d plot the function y = x^2

This is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view/h=135,
      axis lines=center,
      xlabel={$x$},
      ylabel={$y$},
      zlabel={$z$},
      ]

        \addplot3 [
            surf,
            shader=interp,
        ] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the output I'm getting:

[image: output]

This is sorta what I'm looking for (taken from my notes):

[image: Desired output]

Comment: I don't know pgfplots, but the surface this `plot3d` command draws has for equation z = x^2 and not y = x^2. Maybe you are using the wrong command.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll try to find out how to do y = x^2, thanks for noticing it in my place, it's late and didn't even notice it until you brought it up.

Comment: Hmmm, can't seem to find anything to be able to make it, I'll go sleep and try again tomorrow. In the meantime, if anyone has any idea of how I can make this happen, please feel free to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you need to make use of the alternative expression for `\addplot3` which comes in the format `\addplot3({x},{y},{z})`. You also need to add the option `z buffer=sort`.

(See the [PGFPlots Manual](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) at page 128.)

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      view/h=135,
      axis lines=center,
      xlabel={$x$},
      ylabel={$y$},
      zlabel={$z$},
      ]
        \addplot3 [
            surf,
            shader=interp,
            z buffer=sort,
        ] (x,x^2,y) ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, and also thank you very much for the reference in the manual  it will sure be helpful for other things.